# ERROR: Bad argument < Array should be CvMat or IplImage>

Tags: c, opencv

I'm trying to detect different colors at the same time via a web cam. Below is my code but I get an error:

> ERROR: Bad argument < Array should be CvMat or IplImage> in unknown function.

which comes along  with:

> Unhandled exception at 0x7c812fd: cv:: Exception at memory location 0x0011fb70

I think the error maybe caused by

```
IplImage* imgHSV = cvCreateImage(cvGetSize(frame), IPL_DEPTH_8U, 3);
```

but I'm not sure and have idea how to fix it. Can someone give me some hints?

```
    #include "stdafx.h"

    #include <cv.h>
    #include <highgui.h>

// from here to main function is my part.
    IplImage* GetThresholdedImage(IplImage* imgHSV, CvScalar lower, CvScalar upper)
    {       
        IplImage* imgThresh=cvCreateImage(cvGetSize(imgHSV),IPL_DEPTH_8U, 1);
        cvInRangeS(imgHSV, lower, upper, imgThresh); 
        return imgThresh;
    }

    IplImage* hsv;

    CvScalar blue_lower = cvScalar(110,60,10);
    CvScalar blue_upper = cvScalar(120,256,256);
    CvScalar green_lower = cvScalar(40,60,10);
    CvScalar green_upper = cvScalar(71,256,256);

    /* Get the images thresholded for blue and green. */
    IplImage* blue_mask = GetThresholdedImage(hsv, blue_lower, blue_upper);
    IplImage* green_mask = GetThresholdedImage(hsv, green_lower, green_upper);

    int main(){
          CvCapture* capture =0;       

          capture = cvCaptureFromCAM(0);
          if(!capture){
                printf("Capture failure\n");
                return -1;
          }

          IplImage* frame=0;
          cvNamedWindow("Video");      
          cvNamedWindow("Ball");


          while(true){

                frame = cvQueryFrame(capture);            
                if(!frame) break;

                frame=cvCloneImage(frame); 
                cvSmooth(frame, frame, CV_GAUSSIAN,3,3); 

                IplImage* imgHSV = cvCreateImage(cvGetSize(frame), IPL_DEPTH_8U, 3); 
                cvCvtColor(frame, imgHSV, CV_BGR2HSV); 
                IplImage* imgThresh = GetThresholdedImage(imgHSV, blue_lower, blue_upper);
                IplImage* imgThresh2 = GetThresholdedImage(imgHSV, green_lower, green_upper);
                cvSmooth(imgThresh, imgThresh, CV_GAUSSIAN,3,3);
                cvSmooth(imgThresh2, imgThresh2, CV_GAUSSIAN,3,3);
                cvShowImage("Ball", imgThresh);  
                cvShowImage("Ball2", imgThresh2);
                cvShowImage("Video", frame);


                cvReleaseImage(&imgHSV);
                cvReleaseImage(&imgThresh);   
                cvReleaseImage(&imgThresh2);
                cvReleaseImage(&frame);


                int c = cvWaitKey(10);
                if((char)c==27 ) break;      
          }

          cvDestroyAllWindows() ;
          cvReleaseCapture(&capture);     

          return 0;
    }
```

Comment: one question, why do you have the line `frame=cvCloneImage(frame);`?

Comment: @alrikai `frame` is [not allowed](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/highgui/doc/reading_and_writing_images_and_video.html?highlight=cvqueryframe#IplImage*%20cvQueryFrame%28CvCapture*%20capture%29) to be modified unless it is cloned first.

Comment: Considering your [other post](http://stackoverflow.com/q/17517921/1601291), you might want to consider learning C a little better before you just [copy-paste code](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17478700/1601291) willy-nilly. You can find some good books at the bottom of [this page](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/c/info). I mean no offense by this -- but having a good grasp of the language is important before tackling tougher problems like copmuter vision.

Comment: you are right i should have started with the basic before tackling such a problem, it is a part of my assignment. thanks for your advance .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you might want to read up on [pre-main initialization](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17530257/1601291). Your problem is not in the line:

```
IplImage* imgHSV = cvCreateImage(cvGetSize(frame), IPL_DEPTH_8U, 3);
```

but in this one:

```
IplImage* blue_mask = GetThresholdedImage(hsv, blue_lower, blue_upper);
```

`blue_mask` (and `green_mask`, too) must be calculated **before your call to `main()`**. However, you also have declared `IplImage* hsv;` without initializing it, hence the error saying you have a bad argument. `hsv` will either be `NULL` or some uninitialized garbage, both of which are Very Bad Things.

To fix the problem, simply delete the lines declaring `hsv`,`blue_mask`, and `green_mask`. Then your program will work as you expect.